# Можно ли так сказать: "густой город"?

Tags: словосочетания, орфоэпия

Какой же Подольск яркий и **густой город**.

Comment: Сказать-то так можно. Боюсь только, что Вас никто не поймёт.

Comment: Спрос на ГУСТО резко подскочил. Густо-оранжевый город.

Answer (score 2):

Эпитет "густой" плохо сочетается с такими "штучными" понятиями, которые в метафорическом смысле нельзя уподобить веществу, свойством которого является плотность, концентрация или вязкость (жидкость, газ и пр.) - город остаётся "*твёрдым*" и мысленно представляется в геометрических очертаниях (в отличие от голоса или цвета, которым порой приписывают "густоту"). Поэтому здесь "густота" оказывается странной и **непонятной**, в отличие от эпитета "*густонаселённый*" - здесь веществу уподобляется не город непосредственно, а его население, которое даже формально может характеризоваться "плотностью" (количество жителей на единицу площади). Если вы имели в виду что-либо подобное, то формальный термин "густонаселённый" можно заменить напр. на "*оживлённый*"; либо можно дополнить "яркий" характеристикой *насыщенности цвета* ("насыщенно-яркий") - для выражения общего *зрительного впечатления* от города (отдельно взятый эпитет "насыщенный" был бы двусмысленен - насыщен чем/кем?).

Answer (score 0):

Из словаря: ГУСТОЙ  2. Г. цвет (насыщенный, яркий, сочный). 5. Трад.-нар. Полнозвучный, низкий (о звуке, голосе).

Город тоже имеет свою цветовую окраску и  звучание. И тогда получаем:

**Какой же Подольск яркий, насыщенный, полнозвучный  город**. Или что-то в этом роде.